# Argument problem when passed to Model in custom extension

Tags: magento2, model, di

this model extend `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` called in new controller from backend grid created with a uiComponent

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context, //required
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, //required
    \Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\ResourceModel\Banner $resource, //required
    \Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\Collection $resourceCollection, //required
    \Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\BannerFactory $bannerFactory, //optional
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, //optional
    \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog $monolog, //optional
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_bannerFactory = $bannerFactory;
    $this->_monolog = $monolog;
    if ($storeViewId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()) {
        $this->_storeViewId = $storeViewId;
    }
}
```

Everything seem ok but after i clear `cache`, `generation`
Magento show error Recoverable Error: Argument 4 passed to Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\Banner::__construct() must be an instance of Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\Collection, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult given

my di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">ves_bannermanager_banner</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">ves_banner_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">banner_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\ResourceModel\Banner</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Tested in php 5.5.15 magento 2.02
How to fix it

Answer (score 2):

You need to change virtualType name.

```
<virtualType name="Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\**Grid**\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">ves_bannermanager_banner</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">ves_banner_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">banner_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vnecoms\BannerManager\Model\ResourceModel\Banner</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

I guess virtualType redeclare your collection class.